# Microsoft sync framework updated rows not synced

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

i try to sync tables from server ( sql server 2008 R2 ) to my CE SQL 3.5 Using Microsoft sync framework , the sync process work fine when there is new rows inserted to server DB ( if i synced from the server or Through Internet ) , but when there is some rows got updated the updated rows don't sync DownloadChangesFailed when i connect to the WCF service Through Internet , but when i sync from the Server its work fine .

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to the ApplyChangesFailed on your local provider (the destination) and you should get information on why the changes are not being applied. it could be because of a conflict or an error.